# Compile Error: Illegal assignment from List<Opportunity> to List<Opportunity>

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I am trying to find how to go about resolving this error.

Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from List to List at line 4 column 21

```
trigger productupdate on Opportunity (after insert,after update)
     {      
      List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Production_date__c,(select id,ServiceDate from OpportunityLineItems)from Opportunity];
                for(Opportunity op:opp)
                {
                    date olddate=oldMap.get(op.id).Production_date__c;
                    date newdate=newMap.get(op.Production_date__c);
                    integer diffdays=olddate.daysbetween(newdate);
                    for(OpportunityLineItem opl:op.OpportunityLineItem)
                    {
                        opl.ServiceDate =(op.diffdays+opl.ServiceDate);
                    }
                 }
                 update opp;
                 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might have a class in the system with the name `opportunity`.

Either rename that class to something or instead of `Opportunity` use `System.Opportunity`

Comment: thanks it worked, I had the apex class in the same name opportunity